# USB tethering from Android speed limited

Tags: networking, usb-modem, tethering

I am installing Ubuntu 14.10 on workstation.

Since i have not wifi card, i am using my huawei mate to usb tethering. The phone is Android kitkat 4.4.2

Network-Manager set up connection correctly, the strange things is download speed go up to 40KB/sec MAX. Actually there are no other processes taking bandwidth, either on phone and on pc. The same thing happen on fedora 20. On win connection speed is 300 KB/sec the same on OSX, and on phone.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046b:ff10 American Megatrends, Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046b:ff01 American Megatrends, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:1050 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub</code>

     ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep usb
[    0.728139] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.728149] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.728169] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    4.401783] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    4.401785] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    4.401786] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    4.401788] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-23-generic ehci_hcd
[    4.401789] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.7
[    4.417772] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    4.417774] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    4.417775] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    4.417777] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-23-generic ehci_hcd
[    4.417778] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.7
[    4.418210] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    4.418211] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    4.418213] usb usb3: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    4.418214] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-23-generic uhci_hcd
[    4.418216] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    4.418573] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    4.418575] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    4.418576] usb usb4: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    4.418578] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-23-generic uhci_hcd
[    4.418579] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.1
[    4.418949] usb usb5: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    4.418951] usb usb5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    4.418953] usb usb5: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    4.418954] usb usb5: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-23-generic uhci_hcd
[    4.418955] usb usb5: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.2
[    4.419282] usb usb6: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    4.419284] usb usb6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    4.419285] usb usb6: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    4.419287] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-23-generic uhci_hcd
[    4.419288] usb usb6: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    4.419646] usb usb7: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    4.419648] usb usb7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    4.419650] usb usb7: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    4.419651] usb usb7: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-23-generic uhci_hcd
[    4.419652] usb usb7: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.1
[    4.419964] usb usb8: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    4.419966] usb usb8: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    4.419968] usb usb8: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    4.419969] usb usb8: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-23-generic uhci_hcd
[    4.419971] usb usb8: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.2
[    4.713933] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    4.846849] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5567
[    4.846852] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    4.846854] usb 1-2: Product: Cruzer Blade
[    4.846855] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[    4.846856] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 200602658113ECA114C5
[    4.855864] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    4.856401] scsi6 : usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[    4.856464] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    4.864329] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    5.274102] usb 2-5: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    5.423086] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=046b, idProduct=ff01
[    5.423091] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    5.423094] usb 2-5: Product: Generic Hub
[    5.423097] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: American Megatrends Inc.
[    5.423100] usb 2-5: SerialNumber: serial
[    5.662242] usb 6-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    5.827741] usb 6-1: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0745
[    5.827746] usb 6-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.827749] usb 6-1: Product: Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0
[    5.827752] usb 6-1: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[    5.864027] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    5.864028] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    5.871817] input: Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/0003:045E:0745.0001/input/input5
[    5.872188] hid-generic 0003:045E:0745.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
[    5.872497] input: Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.1/0003:045E:0745.0002/input/input6
[    5.872886] hid-generic 0003:045E:0745.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input1
[    5.890899] input: Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.2/0003:045E:0745.0003/input/input7
[    5.891462] hid-generic 0003:045E:0745.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input2
[    6.198401] usb 7-2: new low-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    6.579518] usb 7-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c517
[    6.579523] usb 7-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    6.579527] usb 7-2: Product: USB Receiver
[    6.579529] usb 7-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    6.636661] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb7/7-2/7-2:1.0/0003:046D:C517.0004/input/input8
[    6.637063] logitech 0003:046D:C517.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-2/input0
[    6.637392] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb7/7-2/7-2:1.1/0003:046D:C517.0005/input/input9
[    6.638350] logitech 0003:046D:C517.0005: input,hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-2/input1
[    6.694710] usb 2-5.1: new low-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[    6.799956] usb 2-5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046b, idProduct=ff10
[    6.799961] usb 2-5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    6.799965] usb 2-5.1: Product: Virtual Keyboard and Mouse
[    6.799967] usb 2-5.1: Manufacturer: American Megatrends Inc.
[    6.799970] usb 2-5.1: SerialNumber: serial
[    6.801779] input: American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-5/2-5.1/2-5.1:1.0/0003:046B:FF10.0006/input/input10
[    6.802069] hid-generic 0003:046B:FF10.0006: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.7-5.1/input0
[    6.803148] input: American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-5/2-5.1/2-5.1:1.1/0003:046B:FF10.0007/input/input11
[    6.803525] hid-generic 0003:046B:FF10.0007: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.7-5.1/input1
[   11.103742] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[   11.237479] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1052
[   11.237484] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[   11.237487] usb 1-3: Product: Android
[   11.237490] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Android
[   11.237493] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 022DHQ2134003728
[   20.327669] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   20.602629] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[   20.735780] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1050
[   20.735786] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[   20.735789] usb 1-3: Product: Android
[   20.735792] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Android
[   20.735794] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: "Present":-)
[   20.793308] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[   20.809230] rndis_host 1-3:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1a.7-3, RNDIS device, 82:85:cc:e9:7d:d5
[   20.809252] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
```

As you can see, I am on a path to install but with this speed it is taking forever

accept

Answer (score 0):

Well a few questions come to mind, but I'm gonna take a stab at it.

1. When you said you get great speeds in Windows, was it with this same computer?
2. Do you have a firewall such as UFW enabled? `sudo ufw status` Will tell you if enabled or not. If it's, try disable it to see if improved speed `sudo ufw disable`.

#### What I think the real issue is

You have a bunch of USB devices connected looking through your log and USB only has so much bandwidth. I'm on mobile so I can't see your post as I type this, but I think I seen a few different USB drives, as well as a keyboard and mouse and some kind of USB Bluetooth device.

Unhook all USB except your keyboard, mouse and phone and then see if you get better speeds.

I think I've seen a USB hub in there somewhere too, if so, is the phone connected to hub or actual USB port on PC?

Comment: Wel the only usb devices pluged in are keyboard and mouse, the usb memory was removed, there not hub!So what i can do ?

Comment: Okay. So we know it not usb bandwidth since 1. You said used Windows on same machine with good speed and 2. Just as a test the only usb devices were phone and keyboard/mouse and you still got crap speed (or did it slightly improve?) . I will do some more looking. Things were hectic, but now my pi 2 came in. Just gonna set that up and then this issue will get more attention.

Comment: Not improved, like a fisical limit, bitrate don't go over 40KB/s never. I have try to change bios setting to usb, i'am on Tyan s7025 dual cpu server board, no change.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** This is not a solution using your existing setup, but it might very well work

Have you tried using the app *PdaNet+*? PdaNet+ contains both PdaNet and FoxFi. I haven't used either in about a year, but when I was away for work and still had unlimited data (with Verizon) FoxFi helped me use my phone as a hotspot without any additional hotspot fees. I used in excess of 60 gigs a month without my bandwidth being limited as well. On LTE I was getting over 25 mbps.

**Note:** PdaNet+ and FoxFi only works with android phones, but I see you're covered there. Also, if your phone does not physically have the ability to support the hotspot feature you can also use USB tethering with PdaNet+

You can get the app here: **[PdaNet+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pdanet)**

Comment: PdaNet+ work whit client on pc side, Windows and OSX, also problem is on usb. is desktop not a laptop no wifi